# Checking for Write Combined memory

Tags: c++, windows

With C++/Windows, how do I check if an allocated memory block is write combined? I haven't allocated the memory myself but have access to it.

Comment: Isn't that something that happens at the hardware level, invisible  to the program?

Comment: PAGE_WRITECOMBINE to VirtualAllocEx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ok, that's another use of [the same term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-combining). Very confusing!

Comment: What's wrong with VirtualQueryEx?